# ethernet connection of nxp processor

Tags: schematics, altium, ethernet, microprocessor, nxp

ı designed a  [circuit  schematic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YovNHCL-PueUl3UHNoNV9GRzA) by using  altium designer  to ethernet connection of my processor  [(nxp lpc43s50fet256)](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC43S50_30_20.pdf)
ı added a circuit schematic as altium designer file .You can see my complete circuit schematic .I explained my question but maybe ı was not clear .Therefore let me clerify my question again. Firstly ı have nxp lpc43s50fet256 processor and ı want to design a board via using this processor .However when ı design a schematic fr ethernet connection of my processor , ı really didn't understand some parts. Firstly ı found the ethernet pins of my processor and ı connected processor pins to my lan8720 tranciever . I thought that this was wrong.
ı think that processor gives only 1 and 0 's and how can ı possibly make ethernet connection without using any part between processor pins and lan8720 . If my connection is true ,what is the reason? .If my connection is wrong ,What is the reason?

Comment: You link to a SchDoc file, how am I to view your schematic? Secondly, most processor manufacturers provide some reference schematic for the uses of their products, either in the datasheet or in some other document (often a technical note or a reference design). Did you search for such?

Comment: firsly  there is no enough information about the ethernet   ,and secondly the link of image file  [image](http://imgur.com/a/zzFtY)

Comment: here is the [pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YovNHCL-PueUl3UHNoNV9GRzA)

Comment: @süleymanceylan that image is far too small to work with (and it belongs in your question, not the comments, and the "PDF" is not a PDF, but a "SchDoc" file, which I will not start to rename to .pdf and try to magically open on my machine, because that is a common technique for circumventing antiviruses.

Comment: "there is no enough information about the ethernet" are you kidding?? There is more free information available that I'll ever digest in my life!

Comment: "I think that processor gives only 1 and 0 's and how can I possibly make ethernet connection without using any part between processor pins and lan8720." - All the MAC signals are digital (1 and 0's) so provided you have the correct pins connected it should be fine.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface

Comment: Altium will export pdf files so use that or better still if the circuit is small enough a picture and don't add important details in comments they should be part of the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schematic is wrong in so many places (it's an Altium document btw) that I don't know where to begin with; even Altium's ERC check is complaining, how 'bout fixing that first, at least then we'd have designators to work with. It's no wonder your previous thread got so many downvotes.

I took the libery to [create a PDF from your schematics](https://filebin.ca/3XPQOsAC77hj/myschematic.pdf) for those not using Altium.

As for the first issues:

- You have net label floating around, those are not connected to any net. Additionally, name your nets - it's hard to follow the criss-cross lines
- The LEDs on the connectors are always on, you need to connect those to your controller
- Your controller pins are unlabeled, shall we guess which function you intend to use on them?
- Check your RBIAS, 1k seems a little strange
- Your RST is always high, this by itself is not a problem but you won't be able to reset the LAN controller
- MDC/MDIO pins seem to go nowhere except for a pull-up
- You have some net labels (which are text, not net labels) on a connector which seem to go nowhere
- All your net labels are no net labels, they are text only - this will not work .. don't try changing the color - it doesn't help; they need to be net labels
- You connect AVDD directly to the center taps, doesn't look correct to me
- You do not generate AVDD anywhere ... you might think it comes from VCC via an inductor but again, this is no net label, it's text

Sorry, but you will need to start with Altium basics, then proceed from there.

Comment: thanks for your informative approach . I really learned a lot of things from your sugestions but the problems  , that you mentioned about , is not about my question .Yes I downloaded Altium  2 days ago and ı have never  learnt the basics of Altium . However  these mistakes can be corrected .What ı ask is completely different and not about the design  but the working principle of the ethernet

Comment: you can understand easily from my question

Comment: If you want help then I recommend you fix all the problems mentioned in the comments including embedding the images into the question and not as links.